# Power BI API to refresh dataset and dashboard

Tags: api, powerbi

I am trying to refresh the dataset and dashboard once the dataset is loaded with data everyday. I am taking an approach of using REST API to refresh the dataset and dashboard after loading the data into the tables. Are there refresh dataset, dashboard refresh api is available ?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 1):

We're successfully using this:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/manageRefresh.ps1
You can get the groupid, datasetid and clientid as mentioned in the document and it's simple a command line

More information can be found here:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/